# Image to right of 3 elements

Tags: html, css

I have 3 images using `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` in a `<div>`

But I want to have a image to the right of those, expanding as big as how big the other images on the left are combined.

I tried to add a div inside the div, but it just went under it, while I wanted it to go right.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
   <img src="rsc/img/test.png" alt="Join the Discord">
   <img src="rsc/img/test.png" alt="Join the Server">
  <img src="rsc/img/test.png" alt="See our Socials">
  <img src="rsc/img/test2.png" class="rightimg"/> /* Image I want right of the others */
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```css
.items{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  width:100%;
}
.cols {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
img{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="cols">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=1" alt="Join the Discord">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=2" alt="Join the Server">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=3" alt="See our Socials">
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/800?random=4" class="rightimg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way of doing it with only grid

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 3;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 5 / 1 / 7 / 3;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 7 / 7;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=1" alt="Join the Discord">
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=2" alt="Join the Server">
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=3" alt="See our Socials">
  </div>
  <div class="div4">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/900?random=4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 60%;
}

.rightimg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

First three images will be arranged in a row at the left side of the parent element, and the fourth image will be positioned at the right side of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to display 3 images one below another and last image right side of the 3 images. This code will do. As you can see first div is displayed as a row and two div inside are columns . Adjust height and width as you want.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
}
.col1 img{
    width:100%;
}

.col1
{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    
}
.col2 img
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.col2{
    position:relative;
      display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="items">
    <div class="col1">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4974912/pexels-photo-4974912.jpeg" alt="Join the Discord">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4974912/pexels-photo-4974912.jpeg" alt="Join the Server">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4974912/pexels-photo-4974912.jpeg" alt="See our Socials">
    </div>
   <div class="col2">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4974912/pexels-photo-4974912.jpeg" class="rightimg"/>
  </div>
</div >
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.items{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  width:100%;
}
.cols {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
img{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```